# Child Window Visibility DataTrigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, datatrigger

**Xaml (for a modeless child window, created by `win.Show()`)**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Win_1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Win_1" Height="250" Width="400"
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" >
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=bt_1, Path=Background}" Value="Gold" >
                    <!-- not working: -->
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <!-- working: -->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Thistle"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="bt_1" IsDefault="True" Content="   _Action 1   " HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Background="LightSkyBlue" Click="bt_1_click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#** (Visual Studio 2017, .net 4.7.2)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Win_1 : Window
    {
        public Win_1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt_1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bt_1.Background == Brushes.Gold)
                bt_1.Background = Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
            else
                bt_1.Background = Brushes.Gold;
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bt_1.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the visibility trigger for the child window to work?

Comment: What is "not working"? You are hiding the main window and hiding should work, but you forgot to implement a way to restore hidden window.

Comment: You can add `await Task.Delay(1000)` after you set `bt_1.Background = Brushes.Gold` and set background to something else afterwards so that the window become visible again. Works for me.

Comment: @Sinatr: This is test code, in real life the trigger should refer to ItemsSource.Count. If the source has no items, the window should disappear, and re-appear when new items arrive.

Comment: Describe what is not working please. What happens when you click the button and what do you expect to happens instead? Should it be initially hidden?

Comment: @Sinatr: After clicking the button the window should be hidden, that's all. Instead I see the changed colors.

Comment: Your code works fine. To make absolutely sure the DataTrigger Value comparison works, use `Value="{x:Static Brushes.Gold}"` instead of `Value="Gold"`.

Comment: @Clemens: Good to see you, I know you are a WPF expert. According to my headline the question is about window visibility. The only reason for the coloring is to show that my Xaml code is obviously correct. The fact that the window stays visible after clicking looks to me like a system bug.

Comment: It does not stay visible for me.

Comment: @Clemens: Unbelievable. I tried it with a main window, a child window and a modeless child window (which is the real life case (`win.Show()`), in any case the window stays visible.